Could a WW2-era Grumman Hellcat land on a Saipan-class light carrier using only reverse-thrust generated by a reverse-pitch propeller?
Just that - take away an F6F's arrestor hook and fit it with a reverse-pitch-capable propeller (and, of course, all the other odds-and-ends to make such a system work).
Would it be possible for a decently trained and experienced naval aviator to land such a modified Hellcat on a 186.2m long (611 ft) flight deck with anything approaching safety and repeatability?

It wouldn't be a "WW2-era" Hellcat any longer with that sort of prop on it.  Beta range works well, with immediate reverse thrust, because the prop stays at 100% RPM and the pitch goes negative quickly. Could the original engine spin a prop that way? Maaaybeee.... but it wasn't designed to do that, so now it's not just a new prop, but more mods. Hard to know what the sum of such hypothetical modifications would or wouldn't be able to do.

Thanks for the answer. From what I understand, NACA and BuAer was already testing reverse pitch props on a Curtiss F6C-4 all the way back in the early 30s as a possible method of dive braking - so we're not exactly talking space-age technology here.
